# Why isn't my react app hosted on Hostinger working after reloading?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, hosting, web-hosting

So I deployed an application on hostinger create-react-app and it loads well but when i refresh a page it says "Opps something lost"404 ERROR..the initial load is fine only reloading is a problem.I read some answers online and they suggested to create a .htaccess file in the root
Inside it I added the code

/*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
 */
```

there seems to be no difference though

[Image of file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaaFX.png)

Comment: This appears to be all correct for the .htaccess file and Hostinger. Where exactly are you copying your .htaccess file to when deploying the app? I suspect you just need to move it to your `public` directory to include it with what is deployed. Let me know if this works since I see a ton of SO posts all for this same question that don't have answers or have bad answers.